# Effective way : one transaction for multiple insert or multiple transaction for multiple insert

Tags: javascript, sqlite, phonegap-plugins, database-performance, cordova-plugins

Which will increase my performance or which has faster performance for the following scenario phonegap sqllite db?

Scenario : 
I have multiple insert statements around 1000 statements.

Approach :
1. Having one transaction [db.transaction] for all the insert statements

```
db.transaction(function(tx){
   data.forEach(function(dataItem) {     
         tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (?,?)", [dataItem.id, dataItem.name]});
}, errorInsertingSectorTable, successInsertSector);}
```

or
2. for each insert statement having seperate db.transaction

```
 db.transaction(function(tx){
   data.forEach(function(dataItem) {   
       dbExecution.databaseVar.transaction(function(tx) {
         tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (?,?)", [dataItem.id, dataItem.name]});
});}, error, success);}
```

Which approach has fast performance or have a less overhead for the phonegap app and the best approach?
Please help us clarify.

Comment: Can you execute batch inserts?

Comment: Can you give some example? Even if batch inserts, which will be more effective. Sorry not sure of batch statements in sqllite [sincenewbie]

Comment: See my answer. Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Example of batch insert in sqlite: [Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

It is faster to do a batch insert in a transaction than to run many requests. Imagine how much communication is reduced to a single batch request. If you have many rows you can cut them down to chunks.

EDIT: Because of the fact that suggestion was not enough, let me give you a few more ideas.

- you need to loop all your data
- in each iteration add a (?, ?) to your query string
- in each iteration add the values to an associative array
- call your function by passing the query string an the values

Comment: Cool. Thanks Any answer for my query? Anyone please?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give you more information.